# Script detection of mobile devices - please correct my code

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function isMobile() {
   return preg_match("/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))
}

</script>
if (isMobile)
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.google.com/">
else
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://mail.yahoo.com/">
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Tested with Firefox, it shows the correct site but before redirection the phrase "if (isMobile) else" is shown.
Tested with IE, it shows the wrong site. What am I doing wrong? (I did the tests with my desktop pc.)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I thought it was a fine question.

Comment: No, it’s not a fine question, because it shows a huge lack of very _basic_ understanding about the techniques involved. Apart from JavaScript not being placed inside a script element, the funtion is not actually called, and for the biggest _oops_, he has mixed PHP code in there in a way that makes no sense at all. At this level one should probably not ask questions, but works through some tutorials explaining the very basics first.

Comment: I disagree. This is how people learn. If this isn't the purpose of StackOverflow, what is it? For experts only? BTW, you just suggested that people with questions when they have them. It sounds silly when you say it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You closed your script tag, but then kept writing JavaScript. You need to do all of your JS inside the script tag. This should work, but I didn't test it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function isMobile() {
    return /Mozilla/g.test(navigator.userAgent);
} 


var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta['HTTP-EQUIV'] = "REFRESH";

var url = "";
if (isMobile()){
    url = "http://www.google.com/";
}else{
    url = "http://mail.yahoo.com/";
}
meta.content = '0; url=' + url;
document.head.appendChild(meta);
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I have tested the above code mant times but it is not working. Both Firefox and IE are showing a blank page with the title "Test". No redirection is done.

Comment: I just edited the code. No errors will appear now. It will only look for Mozilla. You will need to enter your regex string again. However, this is not how you do a page redirection. To do a page redirect, you should probably do that on the server, as it can always be prevented on the client. However to do this on the client, instead of saying building the meta object, you would say 'document.location.href = "www.google.com";' That would do your JS redirect.

Comment: Tested the new code, same as above. Nothing is done. All I want to do is to have a web page in two versions, the mobile one for smartphones, tablets etc and another one for PCs. In my expiriments I only do my tests with yahoo and google. In my site will be the html files.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small change to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function isMobile() {
    return /Mozilla/g.test(navigator.userAgent);
} 

if (isMobile()){
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
}else{
    window.location.href = "http://mail.yahoo.com"
}
</script>
</head>
```

and both Firefox and IE open google. If I change your function with mine then nothing happens.